Why does CSS grouping seem to affect selector specificity in this example?
From what I understand of CSS specificity and cascades, if an element is targeted twice with selectors of the same specificity then the latter style should be applied. However, this doesn't seem to be the case in the following example, where the parent selector is first grouped with another of a higher specificity.
https://codepen.io/rjwtrmn/pen/rNbbaoQ
<div class="a">
  I should be blue
  <div class="d">I should be green, but I am pink</div>
</div>

.a,
.b .c {
  color: red;
  .d {
    color: pink;
  }
}


.a {
  color: blue;
  .d {
    color: green;
  }
}

From the documentation and answers to similar questions on here I expected each selector in the CSS group to be independent with regards to specificity calculations. Am I misunderstanding the spec or is it a known bug?

.b .c .d (Your first case) is more specific then .a .d (Your second case)

@MTilsted Sure, but there is no mention of classes .b or .c in the HTML, why is that preventing an override of the selector .a .d?

The specificity of the child selector is based on the largest parent selector in the list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Nesting_and_specificity

Oh you are right. Missed that. Yes it is odd that all browsers takes the unused selector into effect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity  "Similarly, with nested selectors, the specificity weight added by the nested selector component is the selector in the comma-separated list of nested selectors with the highest specificity.". But I must admit I'd also have thought unused selectors would not matter in this case...

@Kaiido it's a decision made due to some performance considerations.

@TemaniAfif which is extremelly rare. When developing a new feature it's usually security first, then user needs and lately implementations issues. I appreciate how the CSSWG has brought so much new features in the last couple of years, but on this kind of edge cases I feel they should have taken more time to discuss alternatives.

Your selectors can be seen like below:


:is(.a, .b .c) .d {
  color: pink;
}

:is(.a) .d {
  color: green;
}
<div class="a">
  <div class="d">I should be green, but I am pink</div>
</div>



And the first :is() has a higher specificity than the second one

The specificity of the :is() pseudo-class is replaced by the specificity of its most specific argument. Thus, a selector written with :is() does not necessarily have equivalent specificity to the equivalent selector written without :is() For example, ref

And if you are wondering why I am using :is()

The nesting selector intentionally uses the same specificity rules as the :is() pseudoclass, which just uses the largest specificity among its arguments, rather than tracking which selector actually matched.
This is required for performance reasons; if a selector has multiple possible specificities, depending on how precisely it was matched, it makes selector matching much more complicated and slower. ref

